# How to use values from a row in a dataframe to assign value in SQL query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am itterating over rows in a dataframe and there are 3 columns I need to use where the value in the row needs to be assigned to an SQL query... row['dfcolumnname'] isn't working

df.columns = ['dfcolumnname1','dfcolumnname2',''dfcolumnname3']

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    SELECT * FROM table

        WHERE tablecolumnname = row['dfcolumnname1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your data structure or information this is something similar to how I would create a dynamic query that takes data from a data frame and turns it into a query.

```
import pandas as pd

def creat_query(df):
    dynamic_query = f"""
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM table
    WHERE 1=1
        AND COLOR = '{df['Color'].squeeze()}'
        and RANGE BETWEEN {df['Start'].squeeze()} and {df['End'].squeeze()}
    ;
    """
    
    return dynamic_query

query = ''

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Color' : ['Red', 'Blue'],
    'Start' : [4, 5],
    'End' : [9, 10]
})

for x in range(0, len(df)):
    query += creat_query(df.iloc[[x]])
    
print(query)
```

Comment: so my dataframe:
color start    end
blue   4    9
red        5        10
green 6 11

and then I want to use the values blue 4 and 9 to query an SQL table

Comment: Updated answer with your new information.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sample data I have

```
dfcolumnname1   dfcolumnname2   dfcolumnname1.1
0   1   table1  22
1   2   table2  33
2   3   table3  5
3   4   table4  6
```

This is the output I got using `df['dfcolumnname2'].map("select * from {}".format).tolist()`. Is this what you were looking for?

```
['select * from table1',
 'select * from table2',
 'select * from table3',
 'select * from table4']
```